# What does 中国爱丽一枚 mean?

Tags: translation, grammar

I don't really speak chinese (except very, very basic stuff), but I try to understand this:

> 中国爱丽一枚～glad to see you！

A chinese person wrote this in a profile in a pen pal app. I'm really confused, because it doesn't make any sense to me.

中国 China 爱 loves 丽一枚 ???

I researched that 丽 can mean "Korea". I guess that might make a little more sense in this context, but what about the 一枚? I have very basic grammar knowlege, so I think the 一枚 should refer to the next sign after it, but there is no such one? Why is there nothing behind 一枚?

Comment: Perhaps a bit more from the Profile would provide some context to decipher the phrase which I believe, 爱丽一枚 is a transliteration of either an English female name, (Alice, Ellie, Ailene), or a phrase, 中国爱丽一枚 = "China loves 丽一枚", or a cryptic play of the words, such as 爱丽 could mean 爱 = "Love", 丽 = "ly", therefore 'Lovely", or it may just simply means "China loves, (中国爱), (you), to pieces, (丽一枚)", as "to pieces" means "very much" in Western pop culture.

Comment: BTW, Goryeo, (medieval Korea), is called 高丽, not just 丽 which simply means "beautiful" Modern Korea is of course called 韩国 which politically means South Korea, and North Korea is called 北朝鲜.

Comment: @WayneCheah Honestly, it's pretty much all I can give you. I could add age, gender, and some Interests of the person, but I guess this would not be helpful for translating. The pen-pal platform is called Slowly and the person is native chinese speaker, intermediate level in English and beginner level in Korean. That's all information I have right now.

Comment: So, coming from the "Korean angle", some people do shorten 高丽 to just 丽 for the old Korea, though it is now considered archaic to call it that, politics aside. As for "Why is there nothing behind 一枚?", well, classifiers in specific context do not always have to be in front. You can have "一个苹果", (an apple), or "苹果一个", (one apple) So, 中国爱丽一枚 could just be paraphrased as "From China with Love for Korea" Young people these days have a generational language all of their own. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Or," 一 枚" has some specialized meaning in Korean?

Comment: "爱丽" could be that person's name. "一枚" is just a cute way of "一个".

Answer (score 1):

爱丽 is just the name of EXO (a nine-member boy group under SM Entertainment in Korea) fans.

一枚=一位（人）

But 一枚 is only a new and informal word popular among Chinese young people.The older generation don't use it.

You can feel it and understand the usages in the following phrases:

小可爱一枚 = 一枚小可爱 = little cute one

一个可爱的人 = a lovely person

野生UP主一枚 = 一个野生up主

sb.+一枚 = 一个+sb.

Answer (score 0):

`中国爱丽一枚` is not a standard morden Mandarin. only few people would understand this.

This sounds like a internet language.

- `爱丽` I haven't heard this before. Maybe refer to `cute girl` ?  whatever, I don't care.
- `一枚` this is more popular than `爱丽`. e.g. you can say: `活捉野生UP主一枚`, here `一枚` means `一位`. e.g. "中国小萝莉一枚`.

All in all, no body would say Chinese in real life, only used on the internet.

Comment: LMAO......WTF....GTH.........YMF...........WYD..........SIY..............